# Good Practice Question: Using DAX vs Doing Everything in the Database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Is it a better practice to do all of the calculations, etc in SQL Server (or whatever database you are using) instead of DAX and avoid DAX at all cost or only use it for minor things?

I'm inexperienced with DAX.

We are having some performance issues with DAX, so I was wondering what the best practice would be.

Comment: *"would like to hear feedback, thoughts, and opinions regarding it."* All of these are explicitly off topic for [so]. Have a read of his page in the [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: Lots of stuff is easier and more sensible if done on the database server. However, Sql Server also commonly costs as much $7k _per core_ to license (and likely to increase over time). The web servers, application servers, and client machines are often **much** cheaper, such that it can be hugely more economical to move that work away from the database.

Comment: What about if money isn't an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data transformations and calculations should be performed at the lowest level they make sense, and in an environment you are comfortable and productive in.

So if all your data comes from a SQL Server you control, and you are comfortable performing data transformation and calculation tasks using TSQL, then you should do much of the prep work, modeling, and basic calculations there.

Note that TSQL is incapable of expressing complex business calculations that can be applied across arbitrary "filter contexts", so you will still use DAX for some measure calculations.

On the other hand, if you don't have a SQL Server you control, or you're mashing-up data directly in Power BI, or you don't have a TSQL skillset, then you should do the data transformation in Power Query/DAX and the business calculations in DAX.